# Stuck on kernel 3.8

Tags: 14.04, grub2, kernel

I have a DigitalOcean VPS that is somehow stuck on kernel 3.8-generic, which is shown when I run `uname -a`.

However, the only kernels in /boot are:
[image]

My sources are such:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Byobu is saying that I am running the 14.04 release.

I have already run `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-trusty linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty`, which shows:

```
linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty is already the newest version.
linux-image-generic-lts-trusty is already the newest version.
```

I have tried running `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-grub2` before rebooting, but this does not work. What do I need to do to restart into the 3.13 kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a DigitalOcean issue, not an Ubuntu Issue.

1. Go to the Control Panel in DigitalOcean.
2. Select the appropriate kernel by clicking settings->kernel and using the dropdown
   [image]
3. Run `sudo halt` on the VPS to turn off the server gracefully
4. Wait a bit
5. Run control panel's turn off as it never seems to think the server is off
6. Use the control panel to turn the server on.

I was performing reboots with `sudo reboot`. That will **not** fix the issue.

Apologies if this is considered off-topic. I really thought it would be a grub configuration issue.